# Using user input to call an integer

Tags: java, int, java.util.scanner

I am a beginner in coding, and I am trying to create a simple program that when a reader types in their name, the program shows how much money they owe. I was thinking of using a `Scanner`, `next(String)`, and `int`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class moneyLender {
  //This program will ask for reader input of their name and then will output how much 
  //they owe me. (The amount they owe is already in the database)

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int John = 5; // John owes me 5 dollars
    int Kyle = 7; // Kyle owes me 7 dollars

    //Asking for reader input of their name
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter in your first name:");
    String name = reader.next();

    //my goal is to have the same effect as System.out.println("You owe me " + John);
    System.out.println("You owe me: " + name) // but not John as a string but John 
                                              // as the integer 5

    //Basically, i want to use a string to call an integer variable with 
    //the same value as the string. 



  }

}
```

Comment: Create a <String, int> map and based on the name (as key), retrieve the int (value).

Answer (score 3):

As a beginner, You might be want to use a simple `HashMap`, which will store these mappings as **key, value** pair. `Key` will be `name` and `value` will be `money`. Here is example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class moneyLender {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("John", 5);
    map.put("Kyle", 7);

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter in your first name:");
    String name = reader.next();

    System.out.println("You owe me: " + map.get(name)); //  
  }    
}
```

**Output :**
Please enter in your first name:John
You owe me: 5

Comment: I didn't know about Maps, thanks +1. Useful solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want the read the user input as a String, it would be a great idea to use the nextLine() method.

You would also want to create a method which takes a String parameter i.e. the names and returns the owed amount.

```
public int moneyOwed(String name){      
       switch(name){

case "Kyle": return 5;

case "John": return 7;

    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int John = 5; // John owes me 5 dollars
        int Kyle = 7; // Kyle owes me 7 dollars


        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter in your first name:");
        String name = reader.nextLine();


        System.out.println(name +" owes me " + moneyOwed(name) + " dollars");
        }
```